# I'm trying to learn ROBLOX lua scripting but there is 1 problem, I forgot how to use the Touch event properly

Tags: lua, roblox

Here is one of my issues.

```
local part = game.Workspace.Part

part.Anchored = true
part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
        wait(0.7)
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health - 2
    end
end)
```

What you see is some very simple scripting in ROBLOX studio.
The type of script this is on is a regular script.
What i need help with is it will not take away health from the player.

Comment: Just a tip, share the errors you get. When I tested your code in my studio, I saw the error, so it was much faster to find the problem, and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use the function `GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)` you need to use the Players service. I fixed the code for you:

```
local part = game.Workspace.Part
-- Get the Players service
local PlayersService = game:GetService('Players')

part.Anchored = true
part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    -- Use the Players Service for the function to work
    if PlayersService:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
        wait(0.7)
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health - 2
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the roblox manual:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/detecting-collisions

> ```
> local part = script.Parent
>  
> local function onPartTouched(otherPart)
>   -- Get the other part's parent
>   local partParent = otherPart.Parent
>   -- Look for a humanoid in the parent
>   local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
>   if humanoid then
>       -- Do something to the humanoid, like set its health to 0
>       humanoid.Health = 0
>   end
> end
>  
> part.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
> ```

> i forgot how to use the Touch even properly

That's why people write manuals. So you don't have to remember everything.

Comment: It's also possible to use the function GetPlayerFromCharacter(), as he did. It was just a small mistake